# Oauth 1.0 - Connection to an Api

Tags: php, api, oauth

I am trying to make a connection to an API that will provide my website with information about cars and other stuff. The problem is that I can connect with it from PostMan because it generates a signature and a nounce.
The problem that I am suffering is that when I want to connect throw PHP the OAUTH class is not generating the nounce and the signature so I can´y connect.
I have also tried with CURL and anything better happened.

My current code is this:

```
$config = array(
    'consumer_key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'consumer_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'request_uri' => 'http://bdc.autobild.es/autobild'
);
$oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], 
$config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1); 
$requestTokenInfo = $oauth->getRequestToken('http://bdc.autobild.es/autobild/','http://localhost/myfolder/');
d($requestTokenInfo);

$accessTokenInfo = $oauth->getAccessToken('http://bdc.autobild.es/autobild/');
d($accessTokenInfo);

$requestInfo = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
d($requestInfo);

$oauth->fetch("http://bdc.autobild.es/autobild/list?type=coche");
$data = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
d($data);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this to authenticate or is this to do an API request after you've authenticated?

Comment: The first part is to authenticate and the second one is to get a list of cars in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was that an argument was missing here:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], $config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1);
```

The correct way is:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], $config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
```

So, the complete code is like this:

```
    $config = array(
        'consumer_key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'consumer_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    );

    $oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], $config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);    

    $requestInfo = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();

    $oauth->fetch("http://example.es/list?type=car");
    $data = $oauth->getLastResponse();
    var_dump($data);
```

Thank´s everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I authenticate to an OAuth service, maybe it will be useful:

**signin.php**

```
//Gets the request token 
session_start();
$oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], $config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM); 
$requestTokenInfo = $oauth->getRequestToken("<oauth token URL>", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/callback.php");
$_SESSION["tokenInfo"] = $requestTokenInfo;
header("Location: <oauth authorize URL>?token='.$requestTokenInfo["oauth_token"]); //May vary on your OAuth service
```

In **callback.php**

```
session_start();
$oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], $config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM); 
$oauth->setToken($_REQUEST['oauth_token'], $_SESSION["tokenInfo"]["secret"]);
$accessTokenInfo = $oauth->getAccessToken("<oauth authorize URL>");
$_SESSION["accessToken"] = $accessTokenInfo;
unset($_SESSION["tokenInfo"]); //Its work is done
```

Now whenever I need to get some API data:

```
session_start();
$oauth = new OAuth($config["consumer_key"], $config["consumer_secret"], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI); 
$oauth->setToken($_SESSION["accessToken"]["token"],$_SESSION["accessToken"]["secret"]);

$oauth->fetch("URL");
$data = $oauth->getLastResponse();
$requestInfo = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
$responseHeaders = $oauth->getLastResponseHeaders();
```

This will work in the cases you need to perform requests on behalf of a user. The user will be redirected to the service's oauth autorizer and then returned to the callback page with their tokens if they authorize your app.

If the service has provided some methods which are accessible from your app directly (typically getting app usage information and the like is linked to these) then you can probably skip a big portion of this:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($config['consumer_key'], $config['consumer_secret'], OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1); 

$oauth->fetch(url);
```

Comment: I cant get the Access Token, the API always returns "Services_Endpoint_"autobild"_has_been_setup_successfully_" but anything like a token. I dont know if I am authenticated but when I want to fetch the data, API returns this error message "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request"

Comment: @PacoGómezCapón is the API provider offering any sort of documentation of what endpoints need to be used to get the access token?

Comment: They had given to me a small documentation but I only have one endpoint,  key and secret key. I have tried this with Postman and it connects with the API correctly and I can fetch the data like other API , the problem is when I try to do it with PHP. In all cases, with more documentation everything would be easier. Thanks.

Comment: @PacoGómezCapón keep in mind (for the last code), there's more parameters you can use, e.g., the oauth constructor may need the `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI` as the last parameter (default is form) and the `fetch` may need you to specify the http method (e.g. post if you need a post instead of a get)

Comment: Yes, I know. But I have also write this and it continues with the same problem... :(    I am going to edit the first code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another library, i recommand you tu use GuzzleHttp.
To install it you can use Composer .

> {
> "require": {
> "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.5",
> "guzzlehttp/oauth-subscriber": "^0.6.0"
> } }

And for implementation you can process like this

> use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
>
> use \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
>
> use \GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;
>
> $stack = HandlerStack::create();
>
> $middleware = new Oauth1(['consumer_key'    => '','consumer_secret' => '','signature_method' => Oauth1::SIGNATURE_METHOD_HMAC]);
>
> $stack->push($middleware);
>
> $client = new Client(['base_uri' => '<BASE_URL>','handler' => $stack]);
>
> $res = $client->get('<ROUTE_DATA>', ['auth' => 'oauth'])->getBody()->getContents();
>
> $res = json_decode($res);
>
> var_dump($res->title);