# PHP OAuth1 provider for Canonical MaaS

Tags: php, maas

I'm trying to authenticate to the MAAS REST API through PHP but I'm not having any luck finding the best way to do so. Basing on the (outdated) examples here: https://maas.io/docs/snap/3.0/ui/api-authentication for ruby and python you need to send the 3 parts of the key but all examples using PHP OAuth1 have only 2 parts of the key so I'm wondering if there is anything about that would allow me to use PHP with MAAS.

TIA

Comment: Which parts of the key are you referring to? According to this, https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/maas-docs/issues/647#issuecomment-379478724, you can use a blank space for _Consumer Secret_.

Comment: Going off of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591780/oauth-1-0-connection-to-an-api) I can't see where I would add the third part of the key or (in that example) what the callback would be

Comment: I've gotten a bit further with this issue but I'm now getting `Exception caught!
Response: Authorization Error: 'Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: &CtCtyvpdn4gdNHw4g8y8VJsJEKXrrXTb`

Comment: Using this code:
`<?php
try {
    $oauth = new OAuth("CONSUMER_KEY", " ", OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_PLAINTEXT, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);

    $oauth->setToken("TOKEN","TOKEN-SECRET");
    $oauth->fetch("http://10.16.97.10:5240/MAAS/api/2.0/account/?op=list_authorisation_tokens");

    $response_info = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
    header("Content-Type: {$response_info["content_type"]}");
    echo $oauth->getLastResponse();
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
    echo "Exception caught!\n";
    echo "Response: ". $E->lastResponse . "\n";
    }
?>`
Any ideas?

Comment: Got this working with https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber instead, working perfectly now